# RegEx for capturing scientific numbers in MATLAB

Tags: regex, matlab, regex-lookarounds, regex-group, regex-greedy

I have the impression I would have a more elegant and compact way of parsing numbers using regexp. I know how to parse numbers in several formats,

```
str_expr = '[\-\+\d\.E]+';
fruit    = regexp(str_text, str_expr, 'match')
```

And I know how to get a look behind,

```
(?<=test)expr
```

But, what if I want to match several numbers after certain look-behind "test"? I usually do it in two regexp, one for the look behind, and the second for parsing the numbers. For example:

```
str_text = 'bla, ble,... bli, 1     -0.1243E-02    23.123E+03'

% pre-digest: look behind
str_reg1 = '(?<=bli,).*'
fruit    = regexp(str_text, str_reg1, 'match')

% parse numbers
str_reg2 = '[\-\+\d\.E]+'
fruit    = regexp(fruit{1}, str_reg2, 'match')
```

If I try to do it in a single step, I only catch the first number

```
% 1st try..
str_reg_try1 = '(?<=bli,)[\-\+\d\.E]+'
fruit        = regexp(fruit{1}, str_reg_try1, 'match')

% 2nd try..
str_reg_try2 = '(?<=bli,)([\-\+\d\.E]+)+'
fruit        = regexp(fruit{1}, str_reg_try1, 'tokens')
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Sure, consider the input of the example above,
    str_text = 'bla, ble,... bli, 1,     -0.1243E-02,    23.123E+03'

And you have to output the parse of the three numbers with different formats
    1, -0.1243E-02, 23.123E+03, not as a complete string, but a numbers, so that "fruit" yields: >>> [1]     [-0.1243E-02]    [23.123E+03]

Comment: Does your matlab tools support PCRE? If so, try with [`\G`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/continue.html) and `\K` for reset like [this pattern](https://regex101.com/r/xYahfR/1). Actually there is nothing wrong with two steps as it's easier readable =D isn't it.

Comment: thank you bobble :) i will try it

Comment: Do you need the numbers in 1 match `1     -0.1243E-02    23.123E+03` or the numbers in separate matches `[1  ,   -0.1243E-02  ,  23.123E+03]` ?

Comment: [Matlab regex engine](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) does not support `\G` operator.

Comment: If your engine doesn't support the `\G` construct `PCRE,Perl,Boost,etc` and is not `Dot-Net`, then the only way to get the separate numbers is to match using this `(?<=bli,)\s+((?:(?:(?<!\S)|\s+)[\-\+\d\.eE]+)+)` then split group 1 on spaces, or get all matches using `\S+`, which is the same as split.

Comment: I think you can stick to your approach. Probably, `fruit    = regexp(str_text, 'bli,(.*)', 'tokens')` is more efficient as the first step.

Answer (score 0):

If my guess might be close, then here, we are looking to collect the digits. I'm positive that we might want to break the string to two or more parts before we pass it to RegEx engine:

```
bla, ble,... bli,
1     -0.1243E-02    23.123E+03
```

Then, in this case, we may not even need regular expression.

---

Or we might be wanting to just integrate some simple expressions such as:

```
(.+?bli,)|([0-9-E.\-+]+)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IswKeM/1/)

Also, I think the advice from [bobble bubble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5527985/bobble-bubble) in the comment is a much better choice ([link](https://regex101.com/r/xYahfR/1)):

```
(?:\G(?!^)|bli,)\s+\K[-+\d.E]+
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/IswKeM/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]